# Add column and fill missing value based on other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For the following input data, I need to fill missing `office_number`s and create one column to distinguish if `office_number` is original or afterwards filled one.

Here is the example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1010084420','1010084420','1010084420','1010084421','1010084421','1010084421','1010084425'],
                   'building_name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'East Tower', 'East Tower', 'West Tower', 'T1'],
                   'floor': ['1', '1', '2', '10', '10', '11','11'],
                   'office_number':['', '','205','','','', '1101-1105'],
                   'company_name': ['Ariel Resources Ltd.', 'A.O. Tatneft', '', 'Agrium Inc.', 'Creo Products Inc.', 'Cott Corp.', 'Creo Products Inc.']})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           id building_name floor office_number          company_name
0  1010084420             A     1                Ariel Resources Ltd.
1  1010084420             A     1                        A.O. Tatneft
2  1010084420             A     2           205                      
3  1010084421    East Tower    10                         Agrium Inc.
4  1010084421    East Tower    10                  Creo Products Inc.
5  1010084421    West Tower    11                          Cott Corp.
6  1010084425            T1    11     1101-1105    Creo Products Inc.
```

I need to fill the `office_number` when it's empty for the office of same `id`, `building_name` and `floor`, with the following rule: `value of floor` + `F` + `001, 002, 003, etc.`; and create one column `office_num_status`, when it's not null, insert `original`, otherwise `filled`.

This is the final expected result:

```
           id building_name floor office_num_status office_number  \
0  1010084420             A     1            filled         1F001   
1  1010084420             A     1            filled         1F002   
2  1010084420             A     2          original           205   
3  1010084421    East Tower    10            filled        10F001   
4  1010084421    East Tower    10            filled        10F002   
5  1010084421    West Tower    11            filled        11F001   
6  1010084425            T1    11          original     1101-1105   

           company_name  
0  Ariel Resources Ltd.  
1          A.O. Tatneft  
2                        
3           Agrium Inc.  
4    Creo Products Inc.  
5            Cott Corp.  
6    Creo Products Inc.
```

I have done so far is created columns `office_num_status` but all values are `original`s:

```
# method 1
df['office_num_status'] = np.where(df['office_number'].isnull(), 'filled', 'original')

# method 2
df['office_num_status'] = ['filled' if x is None else 'original' for x in df['office_number']]

# method 3
df['office_num_status'] = 'filled'
df.loc[df['office_number'] is not None, 'office_num_status'] = 'original'
```

Could someone can help me to finish this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare missing string instead missing value, add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and fill non exist values:

```
mask = df['office_number'] == ''
df.insert(3, 'office_num_status', np.where(mask, 'filled', 'original'))
s = df.groupby(['id','building_name','floor']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
df.loc[mask, 'office_number'] = df['floor'].astype(str) + 'F' + s
print (df)
           id building_name floor office_num_status office_number  \
0  1010084420             A     1            filled         1F001   
1  1010084420             A     1            filled         1F002   
2  1010084420             A     2          original           205   
3  1010084421    East Tower    10            filled        10F001   
4  1010084421    East Tower    10            filled        10F002   
5  1010084421    West Tower    11            filled        11F001   
6  1010084425            T1    11          original     1101-1105   

           company_name  
0  Ariel Resources Ltd.  
1          A.O. Tatneft  
2                        
3           Agrium Inc.  
4    Creo Products Inc.  
5            Cott Corp.  
6    Creo Products Inc.
```

Comment: `df.insert(3, 'office_num_status', np.where(mask, 'filled', 'original'))`, may I ask, what 3 stands for here?

Comment: @ahbon - it means 3.rd column - [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Another question: `isnull()`, `is None`, `==""`, why first two don't work out at this case?

Comment: @ahbon - it depends of data. If no data it should be NaN - then need `isnull` or `isna`, if empy string need `== ''`.